# C# MySQL joins 3 tables

Tags: c#, mysql, xampp

I am currently using C# and Mysql (XAMPP). I have 3 tables as shown below:

```
tblILearnQuestion : IlearnQuestionId, Question

tblILearnAnswer : ILearnAnswerId, ILearnQuestionId, StudentId, dateSubmited

tblILearnMarks : ILearnMarkId, ILearnAnswerId, Comments, mark
```

I need a single query to get the following data : `question, studentid , mark and comment`. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM tblIlearnQuestion 
INNER JOIN tblilearnanswer ON 
    tblilearnquestion.ilearnquestionid = tblilearnanswer.ilearnquestionid 
INNER JOIN ilearnmarks ON 
    tblilearnanswer.ilearnanswerid = tblilearnmarks.ilearnanswerid
```

It says some columns does not exist and I have checked, I did name the columns correctly as it is in my database.

Comment: It is probably the third table's name which is different from what you said earlier in the question but post the exact error message if it is not that.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have wrong name for the table in the second join. You wrote that your table name is **tblILearnMarks** but you used **ilearnmarks** in the query. As you can see **tbl** prefix is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is just a bit off with the joins. This should straighten things up:

```
select * 
from tblIlearnQuestion 
  inner join tblilearnanswer on tblilearnquestion.ilearnquestionid = tblilearnanswer.ilearnquestionid 
  inner join tblilearnmarks on tblilearnmarks.ilearnanswerid = tblilearnanswer.ilearnanswerid
```